# How to free allocated memory in this block of C code?

Tags: c

I am running valgrind on my code and it shows that I did not free my memory when I used malloc. I tried to free it but it gives me the same message. Any suggestions on how this might be fixed?

Thanks!

```
/** 
* Read all the words from the given file, an return them as a
* linked list.
*/
Node *readWords( char *filename )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );

    if ( !fp ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Can't open file: %s\n", filename );
        usage();
    }

    Node *list = NULL;

    while ( true ) {
        int ch = fgetc( fp );

        while ( ch != EOF && ! wordChar( ch ) )
            ch = fgetc( fp );

        Node *n = (Node *) malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

        int len = 0;
        while ( wordChar( ch ) ) {
            if ( len < WORD_MAX )
                n->word[ len++ ] = toLower( ch );

            ch = fgetc( fp );
        }

        n->word[ len ] = '\0';

        if ( len == 0 ) {
           return list;
        }

        n->next = list;

        list = n;

        free(n);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  if ( argc != 2 )
    usage();

  Node *list = readWords( argv[ 1 ] );
  list = sortList( list );

  reportWords( list );

  while (list) {

     Node *next = list->next;
     free( list );
       list = next;
  }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the part where I free the nodes after I use them in the list.

```
/** Insertion sort on a linked list. */
Node *sortList( Node *list )
{
  Node *newList = NULL;

  while ( list ) {

    Node *n = list;
    list = list->next;

    Node **target = &newList;
    while ( *target && strcmp( n->word, (*target)->word ) >= 0 )
      target = &(*target)->next;

    n->next = *target;
    *target = n;
  }

  return newList;
}
```

Here is the part where it gets sorted.

```
/** Given a sorted list, report the number of occurrences of each word. */
void reportWords( Node *list )
{
  Node *n = list;
  while ( n ) {
    Node *end = n->next;
    int ocount = 0;
    while ( end && strcmp( n->word, end->word ) == 0 ) {
      end = end->next;
      ocount++;
    }
    printf( "%s (%d)\n", n->word, ocount );
    n = end;
  }
}
```

Here is the function where it reports the words(prints them out).

Comment: Your code already contains a bug because of your `free(n)` inside the loop in `readWords`.

Comment: @Alrick If I do that, valgrind gives me a message that I did an invalid free

Comment: @AHunt yes whet i said is wrong, i was following your logic because your were freeing the node each time. But KonradRudolph is right, your code is bugged

Comment: But where should the free go if it is not supposed to be in readWords?

Comment: You don't provide following functions: `sortList` and `reportWords` and you don't provide the definition of `Node`, so it's almost impossible to help you. The origin or your problem might be in the code you didn 't show. Please [edit]  your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Jabberwocky The problem is that the system is not letting me list all the code since they are saying there is too much code. How would I post all the code?

Comment: That's why you should provide a __Minimal__ example. Of course this requires some work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky What do you mean? If you want the whole code, how would I minimize it?

Comment: @AHunt read this link: [mcve]. They explain what to do.

Comment: @Jabberwocky   Just updated the code - added the functions you asked for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189550/discussion-between-ahunt-and-jabberwocky).

Comment: Problem resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two main problems, both in the `readWords`:

```
while ( true ) {
    ...
    Node *n = (Node *) malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    ...

    if ( len == 0 ) {
       return list;
    }

    n->next = list;

    list = n;

    free(n);
}

fclose(fp);
```

You populate a node, add that node to the list, then you immediately free that node making invalid.  Later, when you attempt to read the list, you invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by dereferencing a pointer to memory that has already been freed.  You're already freeing the list at the end of `main` so no need to do it here.

That leaves you with a couple of dangling memory leaks.  When you reach the end of the file,  the `len == 0` check is true so you immediately return from the function.  This leaves the most recent node you allocated (which contains nothing) as a leak, and you don't close `fp`.  You can fix this by freeing `n` inside of the `if` block and using  `break` to get out of the loop, and moving the `return` statement after `fclose`.

```
while ( true ) {
    ...
    Node *n = (Node *) malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    ...

    if ( len == 0 ) {
        free(n);
        break;
    }

    n->next = list;
    list = n;
}

fclose(fp);
return list;
```